# Is selecting the inverse of a regex rule possible within regex

Tags: regex

My friend came to me with a challenge that he feels is impossible but I'm determined to find a solution, he has the string "AWUBBWUBC" and wants to select everything but the "WUB"s. I know using the `\Q...\E` literals I can select the "WUB"s but how would I select everything BUT that?

Comment: One handy option that sometimes works, is to replace “select inverse of X” with “replace X with the empty string”. Not an answer to the question, and in general code application.. also no need for \Q..\E to select WUB. Those enable/end escaping which is not applicable.

Comment: @user2864740, i tried that but the challenge was to select the abc not the wub, its not about the output but the selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your engine's flavor supports `\K`, you can start by matching `WUB` and then use `\K` to forget the match up until that point, then match anything up to the first W of a WUB or the end of the string:

```
(?:WUB\K)?.*?(?=WUB|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Hjk3Mc/1

Another option with `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
WUB(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.+?(?=WUB|$)
```